# Adding a custom back button to NavigationBarController created in nib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


    UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"goback.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(//HERE ! i don't know put what thing !) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];


}
```

I found this example, however I don't know where to put it. My navbar was created in the nib. I could add this code to every view in my navbar, but I only want to write it once.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted would need to either be in each view controller (not view, they are different), or you could create a single view controller class with this code, and descend your other view controllers from it.

Comment: ok I think I get it. Right now, all of the table views that are in the  UINavigationController are subclasses of a SecondLevel class, which is itself a subclass of UITableViewController. I could throw it in the SecondLevel class

Comment: what if I have a UITableViewController and UIViewController that both want to be a subclass of my custom class? is that possible?